# Pattern matching with Complex. Feature or a bug?

Tags: bugs, pattern-matching, complex

fixed in **10.1** (windows)

---

I have run into some strange behavior while doing some pattern matching. First, this works as expected:

```
Exp[2 I u x] /. Exp[Complex[0, a_] u x] :> a
(* 2 *)
```

However, when I replace `x` with `Sin[x]` I get:

```
Exp[2 I u Sin[x]] /. Exp[Complex[0, a_] u Sin[x]] :> a
(* E^(2 I u Sin[x]) *)
```

Also, dropping the `u` returns normal behavior:

```
Exp[2 I Sin[x]] /. Exp[Complex[0, a_] Sin[x]] :> a
(* 2 *)
```

I don't have these problems when I'm not using `Complex`. This looks like a bug to me, but perhaps I am not understanding how `Complex` works. I do notice that `Complex` treats numbers and symbols differently:

```
AtomQ[Complex[0, 2]]
(* True *)

AtomQ[Complex[0, b]]
(* False *)
```

Any ideas?

BTW - I'm using 10.0.2 on Mac OS X 10.10.2

Comment: Since Daniel Lichtblau has added the 'bugs` tag to this question, I think we can take it that Wolfram Research will treat this as bug and we will see a fix for it a future release.

Comment: I thought I had put in a comment but I guess I messed it up. Yes, definitely a bug. Here is a simple example that gives `False` when it should be `True`: `MatchQ[ff[I*u*f[x]], ff[Complex[0,_]*u*f[x]]]`. Change `f[x]` to `b[x]` in both places and it works correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why

```
Exp[2 I u Sin[x]] /. Exp[Complex[0, a_] u Sin[x]] :> a
```

doesn't work as expected, except that

```
MatchQ[Exp[2 I u Sin[x]], Exp[Complex[0, a_] u Sin[x]]]
```

gives

> ```
> False
> ```

However, since the apparently more general

```
MatchQ[Exp[2 I u Sin[x]], Exp[Complex[0, a_] u_ v_]]
```

gives

> ```
> True
> ```

you could use

```
Exp[2 I u Sin[x]] /. Exp[Complex[0, a_] u_ v_] :> a
```

> 2

#### Update

Using `Trace` to investigate further shows that using a single character function name in place of `Sin[x]` works

```
 Trace[MatchQ[Exp[2 I u b[x]], Exp[Complex[0, a_] u b[x]]]]
```

> ```
> {
>   {
>     {{I, I}, 2 I u b[x], 2 I u b[x]}, Exp[2 I u b[x]], E^(2 I u b[x])}, 
>     {{Complex[0, a_] u b[x], u b[x] Complex[0, a_]}, Exp[u b[x] Complex[0, a_]], 
>         E^(u b[x] Complex[0, a_])},
>     MatchQ[E^(2 I u b[x]), E^(u b[x] Complex[0, a_])], True
> }
> ```

but apparently replacing `Sin[x]` with any multiple character function name will fail

```
Trace[MatchQ[Exp[2 I u ff[x]], Exp[Complex[0, a_] u ff[x]]]]
```

> ```
> {
>   {
>     {{I, I}, 2 I u ff[x], 2 I u ff[x]}, Exp[2 I u ff[x]], E^(2 I u ff[x])}, 
>     {{Complex[0, a_] u ff[x], u Complex[0, a_] ff[x]}, Exp[u Complex[0, a_] ff[x]],
>         E^(u Complex[0, a_] ff[x])},
>     MatchQ[E^(2 I u ff[x]), E^(u Complex[0,a_] ff[x])], False
> }
> ```

These trace results seem inconsistent to me. I think you have found a bug in *Mathematica*'s pattern matching.

Comment: Thanks for help. I found a couple other workarounds, including `Exp[2 I u Sin[x]] /. Exp[a_Complex u Sin[x]] :> Im[a]`

Comment: This seems like a bug to me too.

Answer (score 3):

This seems like a bug.  Additional examples that would need to be explained if it is not:

```
foo[2 I u Sin[x]] /.
 foo[Complex[0, _] u Sin[x]] :> bar

foo[2 I u Sin[x]] /.
 foo[Complex[0, _] (p : u) Sin[x]] :> bar

foo[2 I u Sin[x]] /.
 foo[Complex[0, _] HoldPattern[u] Sin[x]] :> bar
```

> ```
> foo[2 I u Sin[x]]
>
> bar
>
> bar
> ```

So the problem is unrelated to `Exp`.  Since `u` does not evaluate to something else and it is not the head of an expression I think adding `HoldPattern` or `p :` should not affect the matching and yet they do.

Comment: I also thought it was probably a bug. Replacing the implicit `Times` by a user defined symbol with attribute `Orderless` also leads to a failed match.

Comment: I was hoping for an answer by you or Simon Woods, as I was never quite comfortable with how `Orderless` works for pattern matching.

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed in **10.1**

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

[image: Mathematica graphics]

code

```
Exp[2 I u x] /. Exp[Complex[0, a_] u x] :> a
Exp[2 I u Sin[x]] /. Exp[Complex[0, a_] u Sin[x]] :> a
foo[2 I u Sin[x]] /. foo[Complex[0, _] u Sin[x]] :> bar
foo[2 I u Sin[x]] /. foo[Complex[0, _] (p : u) Sin[x]] :> bar
foo[2 I u Sin[x]] /. foo[Complex[0, _] HoldPattern[u] Sin[x]] :> bar
```